# Реализация comet сервера

Tags: comet, php

Доброго времени суток! Разбираюсь с реализацией простого comet сервера. Есть такой класс:

```
    class daemon {

    public static function listen()
    {   
        set_time_limit(0);

        ob_implicit_flush();

        $sleep = 5;

        $start = time()+20;

        while($start > time()) {
            $msgs = $_SESSION['comet_messages'];

            if(count($msgs) > 0) {
                break;
            }

            sleep($sleep);
        }

        echo "array: \r\n";
        print_r($_SESSION['comet_messages']);       
    }
}
```

если добавить в массив сессии значение пока действует метод listen(), он все равно выведет пустой массив, но при следующем запуске метода выведет уже нормально массив со значениями. Как такое может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как такое может быть?

Сессии в php сохраняются в обычные файлы. Предположу, что файл сессии читается всего раз, и поэтому в него может быть добавлено что угодно - параллельный запрос не будет его перечитывать. Само по себе приложение PHP не является многопоточным, поэтому надеяться на общую память не имеет смысла, имеет смысл завести какой-нибудь memcached и дублировать данные туда, а при сомнении перечитывать файлы/бд.